# How to fix Firebase_Admin Error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Tags: python, firebase-admin

I'm new to Firebase and I am following their tutorial online. I'm trying to authenticate into a quick DB that I created with a few records. I'm getting the error: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

I've made sure my urllib3 is up to date and confirmed my firebase_Admin is up to date. I've checked my file path for json file and copied my database URL into it.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

#Generated from settings of a project.
cred = credentials.Certificate(r"Path to json file in the same directory as program")

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://mydatabase_from_firebase/'} )
```

I am expecting for a return of 0, confirming it worked, but instead I am getting the error results below:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'
```

---

Full traceback is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/Gaming/Firbase_setup/test.py", line 3, in  from
>   firebase_admin import db File
>   "C:\Users\Gaming\Firbase_setup\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\db.py",
>   line 33, in  from firebase_admin import _http_client File
>   "C:\Users\Gaming\Firbase_setup\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin_http_client.py",
>   line 32, in  raise_on_status=False, backoff_factor=0.5)
>   TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?

Comment: Full trace back. I'm using PyCharm if that helps. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gaming/Firbase_setup/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import db
  File "C:\Users\Gaming\Firbase_setup\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\db.py", line 33, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import _http_client
  File "C:\Users\Gaming\Firbase_setup\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\_http_client.py", line 32, in <module>
    raise_on_status=False, backoff_factor=0.5)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is caused due to the outdated urllib3 package.
I resolved this error with the following solution. You can try it as well.

Go to this file(Got this from the error you have given) -> C:\Users\Gaming\Firbase_setup\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin_http_client.py

Comment the following lines from firebase_admin_http_client.py:

```
    #from requests.packages.urllib3.util import retry
    #DEFAULT_RETRY_CONFIG = retry.Retry(
    #connect=1, read=1, status=4, status_forcelist=[500, 503],
    #raise_on_status=False, backoff_factor=0.5)
```

Also change the **init** parameter as below in the same file:

```
def __init__(
        self, credential=None, session=None, base_url='', headers=None,
        retries=1, timeout=300):
```

Comment: Awesome, that did work. Just to note for people for future reference, that file is in the Firebase_admin folder and it's called _http_client.py. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: thanks for the solution, it indeed works. strange that they still didn't update this in 3 years

Answer (score 15):

Upgrading requests to current version `2.22.0` worked for me.

As the previous answer suggests, some libraries are outdated and can cause this issue.

Answer (score 3):

**uninstall the older version of requests**

```
pip uninstall requests
```

**and install the latest one**

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times i getting **time out** error so that to resolve that

Change `init` to below code

```
def __init__(
            self, credential=None, session=None, base_url='', headers=None,
            retries=DEFAULT_RETRY_CONFIG, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS):
```